# Ajax form submit for wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

So, here is my codes:

**form-checkout.php**

```
<form id="rh_checkout_ajax" name="checkout" method="post" class="checkout woocommerce-checkout"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php if ( sizeof( $checkout->checkout_fields ) > 0 ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details' ); ?>

    <div class="col2-set" id="customer_details">
        <div class="col-1">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_billing' ); ?>
        </div>

        <div class="col-2">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_shipping' ); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>


<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review' ); ?>

<div id="order_review" class="woocommerce-checkout-review-order">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review' ); ?>

<input value="send" type="submit" name="buy_product" style="display:none;" id="rh_product_add_done_click"></input>
</form>
```

**my_js.js**

```
//Ajax checkout submit
jQuery('#rh_checkout_ajax').submit(function(e){

var name = jQuery(this).attr('name'); 

jQuery.ajax({ 
     data: {action: 'contact_form', name:name},
     type: 'post',
     url: ajaxurl,
     success: function(data) {
          alert(data); 

    }
});

});
```

**functions.php**

```
//Ajax submit callback
add_action('wp_ajax_contact_form', 'contact_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_contact_form', 'contact_form');

function contact_form()
{
   echo $_POST['name'];    
}
```

**What happens normally**

So, when a product is purchased, then the user is redirected to `order-detail` page which shows what he/she just bought.

**What I want it to happen:**

I am trying to make it so that the form is submitted via ajax and the user is NOT redirected to the order-detail page, but rather stays in the product page (so, no refresh nor redirect).

I attempted to submit the form via ajax as above but not much of luck.

Could someone help me out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the form from submitting normally.  In your js file, add `e.preventDefault()`.  Something like this:

```
jQuery('#rh_checkout_ajax').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = jQuery(this).attr('name'); 

    jQuery.ajax({ 
         data: {action: 'contact_form', name:name},
         type: 'post',
         url: ajaxurl,
         success: function(data) {
             alert(data); 

        }
    });

});
```